# Calculating the rate of convergence from a plot of a limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, visualization, rate-of-convergence

The [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) represents how quickly a sequence approaches its limit.

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|x_{n+1}-x^{*}\right|}{\left|x_{n}-x^{*}\right|^{q}}=\mu
$$

Here, the rate of convergence is μ

Looking at convergence speed for iterative methods, we know that for a sequence to converge Q-linearly, we see:

$$
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|x_{k+1}-L\right|}{\left|x_{k}-L\right|}=\mu
$$

where the sequence `x` converges to the number `L`.

Can this (rate of convergence) be computed by taking the slope (or 2nd derivative) of a plotted graph that shows the convergence of the sequence (rather than calculating it analytically)?

Comment: If you plot $\,\log(|x_k-L|)\,$ then the slope of the linear fit is $\,\log(\mu).$

Comment: Isn't that assuming a certain growth rate? Log scales are only linear for multiplicative growth rates, but not all series are going to "grow" in this fashion.

Comment: Try it and see if it works for you. I think that it will work. Please consult the Wikipedia article [Rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) for some examples for $q=1$ linear convergence which you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about a sequence where
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-L|}{|x_{n}-L|^q}=\mu. \tag{1} $$
Define the associated sequence
$$ y_n := \log|x_{n}-L|. \tag{2} $$
Now equation $(1)$ can be written as
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (y_{n+1} - q\,y_n) =\log\mu . \tag{3} $$
In the case where $\,q=1\,$ the condition is
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (y_{n+1} - \,y_n) =\log\mu . \tag{4} $$
When $\,n\,$ is big this is
$$ y_{n+1} \approx y_n + \log\mu. \tag{5} $$
The question asks

> Can this (rate of convergence) be computed by taking the slope (or 2nd derivative) of a plotted graph that shows the convergence of the sequence (rather than calculating it analytically)?

If the sequence $\,y_n\,$ is plotted on a graph, then
the slope of the line that best approximates the sequence is a good approximation to $\,\log\mu\,$ which gets better as $\,n\,$ gets bigger.

If $\,q>1\,$ then use $\,\log\,y_n\,$ instead.

Comment: "the slope of the line that best approximates the sequence as  gets big is log" .... but we don't know  since it's what we are trying to approximate. So how can the slope be taken?

Comment: @Cybernetic The slope of the **line of best approximation** to $\,y_n\,$ is $\log\mu$.